# how to stop re-rendering components (React-redux )?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm using react-router-redux and have nested connect()ed components. This seems to work fine, except that my nested components are re-rendering when state changes.

Probs:
Root have 5 children:
All components are re-rendering if there is any state changes in any one of the children because all components are connect()ed.

How can I render only the required children alone?

(is there any way to using connectAdvanced life cycle method for resolve this probs?

Comment: With shouldComponentUpdate you can control when to re-render a component (depending on returning true or false): https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate.

Comment: this case , shall I use React.PureComponent / react-update-if-changed to reduces the re-rendering issues?. I'm new to react world. Please share yours view and suggestion to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 2):

To prevent the nested children from being re-rendered every time your state changes in the parent component you should use `shouldComponentUpdate` life cycle.

`shouldComponentUpdate` takes in 2 parameters `shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState)`

So anywhere you want to stop re rendering you should return false. As per the docs "Returning false does not prevent child components from re-rendering when their state changes."

[ShouldComponentUpdate Docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate)

Comment: In ShouldComponentUpdate i have to loop through model object and check the value.Consider the redux performance with large store and frequent updates it would not help to resolve the probs .

Comment: you only have to update it when that particular key:value pair from your ```very large object``` changes. You don't have to check each object. This is the only solution that you can use. If there was any other approach I would have had mentioned it.

Comment: Thanks Adeel. the problems is i'm/system not sure which key:value pair been changed because service is take care of object updating process (business logic) , its a black box for us hence we are dispatch(ing) the model object for UI painting. Here i want to decide the re-rendring part. [Note : Object shape is fixed, only the value been changing frequently]

Comment: what do you mean by object shape is fixed value is changing frequently?

Comment: object structure.